# Store and reuse value returned by INSERT ... RETURNING

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, primary-key, common-table-expression

In PostgreSQL, it is possible to put `RETURNING` at the end of an `INSERT` statement to return, say, the row's primary key value when that value is automatically set by a `SERIAL` type.

Question:

How do I store this value in a variable that can be used to insert values into other tables?
Note that I want to insert the generated `id` into multiple tables. A `WITH` clause is, as far as I understand, only useful for a single insert. I take it that this will probably have to be done in PHP.

This is really the result of bad design; without a natural key, it is difficult to grab a unique row unless you have a handle on the primary key;

Comment: What language and client library are you using? Are you trying to do this with `psql`?

Comment: I'm trying to do this in a .sql script, which, as I understand it, can contain plsql. If that is what's necessary, then I'll have to learn it.

Comment: PL/PgSQL can be used inside `DO` blocks and `CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION`. PostgreSQL doesn't support plsql, so you can't use that. If you intend to run the `.sql` script with `psql` you can use `psql`'s backslash commands like `\copy` and `\set`, but these are part of the `psql` client not the server back-end. Please take a look at the PostgreSQL tutorial.

Comment: To be honest, I think this is also the result of bad design; relying entirely on the primary key can result in running into issues with losing handles on your data because of a lack of natural keys.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> ... that can be used to insert values into other tables?

You can even do that in a single SQL statement using a [data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO tbl1(txt)
   VALUES ('foo')
   RETURNING tbl1_id
   )
INSERT INTO tbl2(tbl1_id)
SELECT * FROM ins1
```

Requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or later.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e080bb694d3664ded6f8b92865ffdbf1)* (Postgres 13)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4da8b/1) (Postgres 9.6)</sub>

#### Reply to question update

You can also insert into *multiple tables* in a single query:

```
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO tbl1(txt)
   VALUES ('bar')
   RETURNING tbl1_id
   )
 , ins2 AS (
   INSERT INTO tbl2(tbl1_id)
   SELECT tbl1_id FROM ins1
   )
INSERT INTO tbl3(tbl1_id)
SELECT tbl1_id FROM ins1;
```