# Inserting a row and related rows with autoincrement primary key together

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, sql-insert

Okay, so the title sucks but here is my problem. I have two tables:

- `image`: which holds some basic meta data and has a `autoincrement` primary key `id`
- `imagesize`: which is holds multiple different sizes per image and there S3 url, width, height, etc. and has a foreign key to `image.id` So `image` forms a one-to-many relationship with `imagesize`.

Currently I first create and image with `INSERT INTO image ... RETURNING image.id` and then create the sizes with `INSERT INTO imagesize ...` where I use the returned id.

Is there a way of combining these two INSERTs so there is no additional roundtrip between my code and the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [**data-modifying CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO image  ...
   RETURNING id
   )
INSERT INTO imagesize (..., image_id)
SELECT ..., i.id
FROM   ins1 i;
```

More explanation:

- [PostgreSQL store value returned by RETURNING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627781/postgresql-store-value-returned-by-returning/15627932#15627932)
- [INSERT rows into multiple tables in a single query, selecting from an involved table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471757/insert-rows-into-multiple-tables-in-a-single-query-selecting-from-an-involved-t/10472136#10472136)

#### Your solution

`CROSS JOIN` to a `VALUES` expression instead of multiple `SELECT` statements:

```
WITH new_img AS (
   INSERT INTO image (description)
   VALUES ('An awesome image')
   RETURNING id
   )
INSERT INTO imagesize (image_id, name, url) 
SELECT i.id, v.name, v.url
FROM   new_img i
CROSS  JOIN (
   VALUES
     ('small' , 'http://example.com/img_2_small.jpg')
    ,('medium', 'http://example.com/img_2_medium.jpg')
    ,('large' , 'http://example.com/img_2_large.jpg')
   ) v (name, url);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter) pointed me in the right direction. Since I need to insert multiple rows, the query looks a bit strange, but it works:

```
WITH new_img AS (
  INSERT INTO image (description) VALUES ('An awesome image') RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO imagesize (image_id, name, url) 
SELECT           new_img.id, 'small', 'http://example.com/img_2_small.jpg' FROM new_img
UNION ALL SELECT new_img.id, 'medium', 'http://example.com/img_2_medium.jpg' FROM new_img
UNION ALL SELECT new_img.id, 'large', 'http://example.com/img_2_large.jpg' FROM new_img
;
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/eb08a/3)