# How to determine the auto-generated primary key used as a foreign key for another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-schema, sql-insert

This is a two-part question.  Attached is a diagram for a PostgreSQL database table design.  There are four tables. Table `Main` has a one-to-many relationship with table `Submain`.  Table `Submain` has a one-many relationship with table `Subsub`.  The primary keys for all four tables are serial NOT NULL (so they auto-increment).  Each table has multiple attributes that are not shown here.

[image: PostgreSQL table design]

Question 1.  Multiple users will access this application and database.  When a user accesses an application that uses this database, some of their information will be stored in table `Main`.  Subsequent information (provided by the user and other results based on the user's input) will be stored in tables `Submain` and `Subsub`. My thinking is as follows:

1. User submits information via a form.
2. A `MainId` primary key will be automatically generated and some of the user information will be placed in table `Main`.
3. A record will be inserted into table `Submain` based on the user's input (items in `Main`).  How can I determine what the user's primary key `MainId` is so that I can insert it into `Submain.MainId [FK]` for the new record?
4. A record will also be inserted into `Subsub` and that information will be based on information in table `Submain`.  Similarly, how can I determine `Submain.Submain [PK]` so that I can use it as the foreign key in `Subsub.Submain [FK]`?

Question 2.  There is a many-to-many relationship between `Main` and `Other` (I left out the associative table).  However, in order to insert a record into table `Other`, information is required from `Subsub`.  There will be a one-to-one mapping between `Subsub` and `Other`.  Do I need to draw out that one-to-one relationship OR can table `Other` be populated based on a complex `SELECT/JOIN` statement from table `Main` down to table `Subsub`?  This might be a bad question, but I think that I need to draw a one-to-one relationship and insert a foreign key `SubsubId [FK]` into `Other` instead of trying a complicated SQL statement.

Comment: The general guideline is to make it *one* question per question. Also, your 2nd question does not seem to match your ER diagram. I suggest you split that part into separate question. And please always provide your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to Q1: Use [data-modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) and return the generated serial value with the `RETURNING` clause:

```sql
WITH ins_main AS (
   INSERT INTO main(col1)
   VALUES ('some value 1')
   RETURNING main_id    
   )
, ins_submain AS (
   INSERT INTO submain (main_id, col2)
   SELECT main_id, 'some value 2'
   FROM   ins_main
   RETURNING submain_id
   )
INSERT INTO subsub (submain_id, col3)
SELECT submain_id, 'some value 3'
FROM   ins_submain;
```

Requires Postgres **9.1** or later.
Related answers with explanation and links:

- [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561254/insert-data-in-3-tables-at-a-time-using-postgres/20561627#20561627)
- [Store and reuse value returned by INSERT ... RETURNING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627781/postgresql-store-value-returned-by-returning/15627932#15627932)